# Cannot VirtualBox to find my preseed file - How does preseed files work with Packer

Tags: virtualbox, packer

[image: error message]

I'm newbie to packer, I'm trying to install Ubuntu Os in virtualbox. Unfortunately, when I go to boot try and use my preseed file I get the error message above. Could not find kernel image: preseed/url=http:/ubuntu.

By the way this is all being done by Packer, starting the VM up until when the error message occurs
Below is my template.json

```
 {
    "builders": [
      {
        "type": "virtualbox-iso",
        "vm_name": "{{ user `alias` }}",
        "vboxmanage": [          
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--cpus", "1" ],
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--memory", "2048" ],
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--clipboard", "bidirectional" ],            
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--draganddrop", "bidirectional" ],
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--boot3", "disk" ],
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--audio", "none" ],  
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--nic1", "intnet" ],  
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--nic2", "null" ]
          ],
        "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu_64",
        "iso_url": "{{ user `iso_url` }}",
        "iso_checksum": "{{ user `iso_checksum` }}",
        "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
        "disk_size": "{{ user `disk_size` }}",
        "ssh_username": "{{ user `ssh_username` }}",
        "ssh_password": "{{ user `ssh_password` }}",
        "ssh_timeout": "{{ user `ssh_timeout` }}",
        "guest_additions_mode": "attach",
        "headless": "{{ user `headless` }}",
        "http_directory": "http",
        "boot_wait": "5s",
        "boot_command": [
          "<enter><wait5>",
          "<esc><enter><wait5>",
          "preseed/url=http://{{.HTTPIP}}:{{.HTTPPort}}/ubuntu/{{user `preseed_file`}} ",
          "<enter>"
        ],
        "shutdown_command": "echo 'packer' | sudo -S shutdown -P now"
      }
    ],
    "post-processors": [
      {
        "type": "vagrant",
        "output": "C:/Users/{import/automation/packer/boxes/ubuntu/{{ user `box_name` }}.box"
      }
    ],
    "variables": {
      "headless": "false",
      "iso_checksum": "{{ user `iso_checksum` }}",
      "iso_url": "{{ user `iso_url` }}",
      "disk_size": "256000",
      "alias": "packervm",
      "box_name": "ubuntu_custom",
      "ssh_timeout": "10m",
      "ssh_username": "{{ user `ssh_username` }",
      "ssh_password": "packer",
      "preseed_file":"temp.cfg"

    }
  }
```

This is my file directory structure in case

[image: file directory]
What's the problem and how to retrieve the preseed file?

Answer (score 1):

This have noting to do with Packer, the problem is that you have a incorrect *boot command*. A correct boot command starts with the kernel to load i.g. `/install/vmlinuz`. Example screen shoot:

[image]

Try to start with a known good template and modify it in small steps to your needs. One of the best are [Chef's Bento boxes](https://github.com/chef/bento/tree/master/ubuntu).

For further reading also see the [Ubuntu Documentation on Preseed](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs02.html).